# Bit Twiddling - Confused With This Program's Output

Tags: c, integer, bit-shift, bit-manipulation

So I was messing around with Bit-Twiddling in C, and I came across an interesting output:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0x00FF00FF;
    int b = 0xFFFF0000;

    int res = (~b & a);

    printf("%.8X\n", (res << 8) | (b >> 24));
}
```

And the output from this statement is:

> FFFFFFFF

I expected the output to be

> 0000FFFF

But why wasn't it? Am I missing something with bit-shifting here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: Your integer b is negative so when you shift it right the value of the uppermost bit (i.e. 1) remains the same. Therefore when you shift b right by 24 places you end up with 0xFFFFFFFF.

Longer explanation:

Assuming on your platform that your integers are 32 bits or longer and a signed integer is represented by 2's complement then the 0xFFFF0000 assigned to a signed integer variable is a negative number. If an int is longer than 32 bits then the 0xFFFF0000 will be sign extended first and will still be a negative number.

Shifting a negative number right is implementation defined by the standard (C99 / N1256, section 6.5.7.5):

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. [...] If E1
>   has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is
>   implementation defined.

That means a particular compiler can choose what happens in a particular situation, but it should be noted in the compiler manual what the effect is.

There tend to be two sets of shift instructions in many processors, a logical shift and an arithmetic shift. The logical shift right will shift bits and fill the exposed bits with zeros. Arithmetic shifts right (assuming 2's complement again) will fill the exposed bits with the same bit value of the most significant bit so that it ends up with a result that is consistent with using shifts as a divide by 2. (For example, -4 >> 1 == 0xFFFFFFFC >> 1 == 0xFFFFFFFE == -2.)

In your case it appears that the compiler implementor has chosen to use arithmetic shifts when applied to signed integers and so the result of shifting a negative value to the right remains a negative value. In terms of bit patterns 0xFFFF0000 >> 24 gives 0xFFFFFFFF.

Unless you are absolutely sure of what you are doing it is best to perform bitwise operations only on unsigned types as their internal representation can safety be treated as a collection of bits. You probably also want to make sure any numeric values you use in that case are unsigned by appending the unsigned suffix to your number.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how I missed the fact that the sign stays when you bit-shift.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: It's only true for signed integers, so maybe that's why you've never noticed. Or maybe you've never had the integer in the correct range for it to matter (2's complement representation and a negative value).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII : I learned it by *trying* to shift on the complement of 0 `~0 >> x`. The better way was `~0u >> x`.

Comment: @Richard - as tinman said, it's true for signed integers... but what tinman didn't say is that it's true for signed integers **on your particular implementation**.  This is implementation-defined behavior (not to be confused with unspecified behavior, or undefined behavior).  That same code on another platform is perfectly free to shift in zeros. Don't write code that relies on this behavior if you expect / want it to be portable!

Answer (score 2):

Right-shifting negative values (like `b`) can be defined in two different ways: *logical shift*, which pads the value with zeroes on the left (which yields a positive number when shifting a nonzero amount), and *arithmetic shift*, which pads the value with ones (always yielding a negative number).  Which definition is used in C is implementation-defined, and your compiler apparently uses arithmetic shift, so `b >> 24` is `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Answer (score 2):

b >> 24 gives 0xFFFFFFFF *signed right pad of negative number*

```
List = (res << 8) | (b >> 24)
a        = 0x00FF00FF =  0000 0000 1111 1111 0000 0000 1111 1111
b        = 0xFFFF0000 =  1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000
~b       = 0x0000FFFF =  0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111
~b & a   = 0x000000FF =  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111, = res
res << 8 = 0x0000FF00 =  0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 0000 0000
 b >> 24 = 0xFFFFFFFF =  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
List     = 0xFFFFFFFF =  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

Answer (score 0):

The golden rule: Never ever mix signed numbers with bitwise operators.

Change all ints to unsigned ints. Just as a precaution, change all literals to unsigned too.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t a = 0x00FF00FFu;
uint32_t b = 0xFFFF0000u;

uint32_t res = (~b & a);
```

Comment: the golden rule even: don't use bitwise operators with signed types ;)